# Help with a tpl editing

Tags: html, php, templates, validation

I don't know what I did but suddendly my code isn't acting as it should.

My menu is not showing correctly because I am missing a UL closing tag.

I played with the attatched code but nothing. Attatched is the generated code:

[This is what I want](http://dvartora.com/aaa/UL/good.html)
[and this is what I get](http://dvartora.com/aaa/UL/bad.html)

The missing ul is on line 71.

Please help me.

PHP / TPL Code:

```
<nav id="categories"> 
<ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal"> 
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_widget_categories_start"} 
{section name=thecat loop=$cat_array} 
{if $lastspacer eq ""}{assign var=lastspacer value=$cat_array[thecat].spacercount}{/if} 
{if $cat_array[thecat].auto_id neq 0} 

{if $cat_array[thecat].spacercount < $submit_lastspacer}</ul></li>{/if} 
{if $cat_array[thecat].spacercount > $submit_lastspacer}<ul>{/if} 

    <li{if $cat_array[thecat].principlecat neq 0} class="dir"{/if}> 
    <a href="{if $pagename eq "upcoming" || $groupview eq "upcoming"} 
                    {$URL_queuedcategory, $cat_array[thecat].safename} 
                {else} 
                    {$URL_maincategory, $cat_array[thecat].safename|replace:' ':'%20'} 
                {/if} 
                {php} 
    global $URLMethod; 
    if ($URLMethod==2) print "/"; 
    {/php}">{$cat_array[thecat].name}</a> 
    {if $cat_array[thecat].principlecat eq 0}</li>{else}{/if}{assign var=submit_lastspacer value=$cat_array[thecat].spacercount}{/if} 
{/section} 
{checkActionsTpl location="tpl_widget_categories_end"} 
{if $cat_array[thecat].spacercount < $submit_lastspacer}{$lastspacer|repeat_count:'</ul></li>'}{/if} 
        </ul></li> 
</ul> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the code, I think you have

```
</ul></li>
```

the wrong way round in three places. You want

```
</li></ul>
```

Comment: I don't think so. Have you looked at the files I have attatched?